# Dot and new operator precendence in java

Tags: java, operators, new-operator, dot-operator

I was looking at Java documentation and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) example surprised me:

```
int height = new Rectangle().height;`
```

I always thought in such situation you have to use brackets:

```
int height = (new Rectangle()).height;
```

because [operator precedence table](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) shows that `.` operator have higher predecence than `new` operator, if so then why that line of code is executed like this:

```
int height = (new Rectangle()).height;
```

instead of being executed like this:

```
int height = new (Rectangle().height);
```

Comment: as i´ve seen this document already, i think it CAN be slightly missleading, as the most important factor in this table is the `Associativity` column here.
for the dot it´s `left to right`, which means, it executes the left statment first, as it initializes a new `Rectangle` and will then execute it´s right statment, which is accessing the `height` field. That´s why it´s correct and doesn´t produce an error.

Comment: Note that although `int height = new (Rectangle().height);` does not make sense syntactically, another expression with the dot in the middle makes perfect sense: `Height h = new Rectangle.Height()`